# Read INT64 from Windows Registry

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I'm having an issue reading the `InstallTime` value from the registry in Windows 11. I used [this idea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/may/c-use-modern-c-to-access-the-windows-registry) to read the value, but `retCode` gives me **2** (`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`). The value is there, and I guess there's no need for admin rights to read it. I'm using the following code snippet:

```
UINT64 RegGetQword(HKEY hKey, const std::wstring& subKey, const std::wstring& value)
{
    UINT64 data{};
    DWORD dataSize = sizeof(data);
    LONG retCode = ::RegGetValue(hKey, subKey.c_str(), value.c_str(), RRF_RT_REG_QWORD, nullptr, &data, &dataSize);

    if (retCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        throw RegistryError{ "Cannot read QWORD from registry.", retCode };
    return data;
}

int main(void)
{
    UINT64 dwInst;

    try
    {   double nTimeExpr = (double)RegGetQword(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", L"InstallTime");
        dwInst = _getSecondsFromEpoch(nTimeExpr)
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        dwInst = 0;
    }

    //... Do whatever needed with dwInst

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's been a while have not used Win APIs but you should be opening the registry key first with `RegOpenKeyEx` and then proceed further with `RegGetValue` APIs. Maybe look up some examples on how to query registry values

Comment: Are you possibly running a 32-bit program on a 64-bit OS? they get a different view of the registry

Comment: My bad @user253751, you are very right, that's the reason. Using *Regedit* I cannot find the value InstallTime in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion.

Comment: Then you will have to specify the `RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY` flag when calling `RegGetValue()`